# How to set iOS's ringtone from a tweak

Tags: iphone, ios, ringtone

i'm writing a tweak for iPhone that at certainly point needs to set the ringtone, but i'm not able to find how to do that.
Can someone tell me how to do that, put me in the right direction where to look or just tell me a website where to search or maybe in some wiki?
All i've found are useless answers.

*More Info:*
I need to know how to set ringtone for a tweak so the solution can be only for jaibroken devices.

Thanks!

Comment: This isn't currently possible, and most likely never will be. See the link above.

Comment: Is this one of those apps that secretly changes the ring tone to an advertising message, so when the phone rings in a crowded location like an airport, the company gets free advertising?

Comment: @middaparka Is not a duplicate, asking different thing. I've read all the question that i could find here.

Comment: @Gilbert Le Blanc Absolutly not, i'm trying to do a tweak to do smthing like the nokia's profiles.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot set the user's ringtone using the iOS SDK. If you need this ability, consider filing an enhancement request at https://feedbackassistant.apple.com/. However, as this feature would annoy the unholy poop out of almost every user on the platform, don't hold your breath.

Comment: Not talking about sdk. Thanks anyway.

Comment: You said you were in your question. "just tell me where to look in the sdk" kind of implies SDK-ness.

Comment: Mmh.. You're right, with sdk wasn't right word.. I did mean "put me in the right direction".. I've definitely chosen the wrong word.